# Most efficient way to convert Boost::uint64 to Java

Tags: java, c++, boost, java-native-interface

As a short example I have C++ JNI Code that will grab the filesize of some file and I want to pass that back into Java.

A) Is this a sane approach?

B) Is there a better way of doing this rather than dumping the data into a String?

C++ Snippet:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_test_TestClass_getNumBytes(...) {
  boost::uintmax_t numBytes = 0;
  try {
    numBytes = boost::filesystem::file_size(MY_GLOBAL_FILE_NAME);
  } catch(const boost::filesystem::filesystem_error& e) {
    return env->NewStringUTF("0");
  }

  return env->NewStringUTF(boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(numBytes));
}
```

Java Snippet:

```
private native String getNumBytes();

public void doStuff() {
  final String s = getNumBytes();
  final BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(s);

  final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Comparing: ");
  sb.append(s).append(" to ").append(bi);

  System.out.println("Values should look the same: " + sb.toString());
}
```

Assume Java cannot access MY_GLOBAL_FILE_NAME.

Comment: If it's a java question, why don't you compute the filesize straight away in Java ?

Comment: If you are working in Java, you should be happy that you won't need to write down the value in XML.

Comment: Assume that Java cannot access the file. This is a simple example for a much more complicated piece of software.

Comment: Why don't you just return a long? As the Java File class does as well?

Comment: A long in C++ means different things on different machines. Is casting a boost::uintmax_t to jlong always going to produce the expected value?

Comment: long in Java is defined as signed int64. And that is true on every machine for every version of Java, including all future versions.

Comment: When casting between boost::uintmax_t and jlong you are casting from unsigned to signed. Realistically, I suppose you would never have a file big enough to overflow the jlong the compiler will still complain. I just don't want to hit a situation where jlong isn't enough which is why I was using BigInteger. Maybe I am over paranoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast the `boost::uintmax_t` to `jlong`. It’s very likely that the possible loss of precision remains a theoretical issue. Any I/O API inside Java uses the signed `long` anyway.

If you want to stay prepared for sizes for which the sign becomes an issue, you can still pass the value as `jlong` to your Java code and fix it on the Java side as the overflow does not destroy information and the sign gives an easy to check indicator for the overflow.

The code could look like this:

```
// 2⁶⁴
private static BigInteger twoP64=BigInteger.ZERO.flipBit(64);

public static BigInteger getNumBytes()
{
  long longValue=getNumByteNative();
  BigInteger i=BigInteger.valueOf(longValue);
  if(longValue<0) i=i.add(twoP64);
  return i;
}

private native long getNumByteNative();
```

This is much easier than to construct a `BigInteger` on the native side. And it offers you to proceed conditionally on the Java side, using a `long` as long as it fits and `BigInteger` only when necessary (never, I guess).